# telegram scraper bot failing

Tags: python, telethon

I have found and set up a scraper bot and tried running it through cmd and everything works fine however at the end when I go to scrape members, it comes up with a long script saying the below and doesn't add members to a file, does anyone know what's going on?

```
 File "C:\Users\HOME\Desktop\TeleGram-Scraper-master\scraper.py", line 80, in <module>
    all_participants = client.get_participants(target_group, aggressive=True)
  File "C:\Users\HOME\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\telethon\sync.py", line 39, in syncified
    return loop.run_until_complete(coro)
  File "C:\Users\HOME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 641, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "C:\Users\HOME\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\telethon\client\chats.py", line 507, in get_participants
    return await self.iter_participants(*args, **kwargs).collect()
  File "C:\Users\HOME\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\telethon\requestiter.py", line 113, in collect
    async for message in self:
  File "C:\Users\HOME\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\telethon\requestiter.py", line 74, in __anext__
    if await self._load_next_chunk():
  File "C:\Users\HOME\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\telethon\client\chats.py", line 222, in _load_next_chunk
    results = await self.client(self.requests)
  File "C:\Users\HOME\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\telethon\client\users.py", line 30, in __call__
    return await self._call(self._sender, request, ordered=ordered)
  File "C:\Users\HOME\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\telethon\client\users.py", line 80, in _call
    raise MultiError(exceptions, results, requests)
telethon.errors.common.MultiError: ([None, FloodWaitError('A wait of 28 seconds is required (caused by GetParticipantsRequest)'), FloodWaitError('A wait of 28 seconds is required (caused by GetParticipantsRequest)'), None, FloodWaitError('A wait of 28 seconds is required (caused by GetParticipantsRequest)'), FloodWaitError('A wait of 28 seconds is required (caused by GetParticipantsRequest)'), None, FloodWaitError('A wait of 28 seconds is required (caused by GetParticipantsRequest)'), FloodWaitError('A wait of 28 seconds is required (caused by GetParticipantsRequest)'), FloodWaitError('A wait of 28 seconds is required (caused by GetParticipantsRequest)'), FloodWaitError('A wait of 28 seconds is required (caused by GetParticipantsRequest)'), FloodWaitError('A wait of 28 seconds is required (caused by GetParticipantsRequest)'), FloodWaitError('A wait of 28 seconds is required (caused by GetParticipantsRequest)'), FloodWaitError('A wait of 28 seconds is required (caused by GetParticipantsRequest)'), FloodWaitError('A wait of 28 seconds is required (caused by GetParticipantsRequest)'), FloodWaitError('A wait of 28 seconds is required (caused by GetParticipantsRequest)'), FloodWaitError('A wait of 28 seconds is required (caused by GetParticipantsRequest)'), FloodWaitError('A wait of 28 seconds is required (caused by GetParticipantsRequest)'), FloodWaitError('A wait of 28 seconds is required (caused by GetParticipantsRequest)'), FloodWaitError('A wait of 28 seconds is required (caused by GetParticipantsRequest)'), FloodWaitError('A wait of 28 seconds is required (caused by GetParticipantsRequest)'), FloodWaitError('A wait of 28 seconds is required (caused by GetParticipantsRequest)'), FloodWaitError('A wait of 28 seconds is required (caused by GetParticipantsRequest)'), FloodWaitError('A wait of 28 seconds is required (caused by GetParticipantsRequest)'), FloodWaitError('A wait of 28 seconds is required (caused by GetParticipantsRequest)'), FloodWaitError('A wait of 28 seconds is required (caused by GetParticipantsRequest)')], [<telethon.tl.types.channels.ChannelParticipants object at 0x000001FE552166B0>, None, None, <telethon.tl.types.channels.ChannelParticipants object at 0x000001FE551C1600>, None, None, <telethon.tl.types.channels.ChannelParticipants object at 0x000001FE55696F50>, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None], [<telethon.tl.functions.channels.GetParticipantsRequest object at 0x000001FE548C0370>, <telethon.tl.functions.channels.GetParticipantsRequest object at 0x000001FE548C0430>, <telethon.tl.functions.channels.GetParticipantsRequest object at 0x000001FE548C04F0>, <telethon.tl.functions.channels.GetParticipantsRequest object at 0x000001FE548C05B0>, <telethon.tl.functions.channels.GetParticipantsRequest object at 0x000001FE548C0670>, <telethon.tl.functions.channels.GetParticipantsRequest object at 0x000001FE548C0730>, <telethon.tl.functions.channels.GetParticipantsRequest object at 0x000001FE548C07F0>, <telethon.tl.functions.channels.GetParticipantsRequest object at 0x000001FE548C08B0>, <telethon.tl.functions.channels.GetParticipantsRequest object at 0x000001FE548C0970>, <telethon.tl.functions.channels.GetParticipantsRequest object at 0x000001FE548C0A30>, <telethon.tl.functions.channels.GetParticipantsRequest object at 0x000001FE548C0AF0>, <telethon.tl.functions.channels.GetParticipantsRequest object at 0x000001FE548C0BB0>, <telethon.tl.functions.channels.GetParticipantsRequest object at 0x000001FE548C0C70>, <telethon.tl.functions.channels.GetParticipantsRequest object at 0x000001FE548C0D30>, <telethon.tl.functions.channels.GetParticipantsRequest object at 0x000001FE548C0DF0>, <telethon.tl.functions.channels.GetParticipantsRequest object at 0x000001FE548C0EB0>, <telethon.tl.functions.channels.GetParticipantsRequest object at 0x000001FE548C0F70>, <telethon.tl.functions.channels.GetParticipantsRequest object at 0x000001FE548C1030>, <telethon.tl.functions.channels.GetParticipantsRequest object at 0x000001FE548C10F0>, <telethon.tl.functions.channels.GetParticipantsRequest object at 0x000001FE548C11B0>, <telethon.tl.functions.channels.GetParticipantsRequest object at 0x000001FE548C1270>, <telethon.tl.functions.channels.GetParticipantsRequest object at 0x000001FE548C1330>, <telethon.tl.functions.channels.GetParticipantsRequest object at 0x000001FE548C13F0>, <telethon.tl.functions.channels.GetParticipantsRequest object at 0x000001FE548C14B0>, <telethon.tl.functions.channels.GetParticipantsRequest object at 0x000001FE548C1570>, <telethon.tl.functions.channels.GetParticipantsRequest object at 0x000001FE548C1630>])
```

Comment: Judging by multiple FloodWaitError errors, it seems like too many requests are sent in a given time frame.

Answer (score 0):

Go to scraper.py code in line 80 and make aggressive=False. It worked for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).